# CSS not loading when url contains a trailing slash

Tags: css, google-app-engine, url

I have a j2ee application I'm building and deploying to gae, and for some reason, when there is a trailing slash at the end of my url, the CSS does not load.

For example:

`mysite.com/account` works perfectly

but

`mysite.com/account/` loads the page without the CSS

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

CSS Stylesheets:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link href="/css/rrstyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/grayscale.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <title>My app</title>
</head>
```

I am including this header as a separate jsp, but it works when I go to /account but not /account/ for some reason. I don't understand how that could be.

Comment: Could you include a simple line on how are you linking the stylesheet?

Comment: It's often instructive to load a page with the (firefox or Chrome) network activity debugging tools active. Problems like this tend to jump right out, with an easy solution to follow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of your CSS links have relative URLs. This means they will be interpreted relative to the directory of the URL of the calling page. When the caller URL is `mysite.com/account`, the URL `css/grayscale.css` is interpreted as `mysite.com/css/grayscale.css`. But when the caller URL is `mysite.com/account/`, the CSS URL is treated as `mysite.com/account/css/grayscale.css`.

The simplest solution is to use absolute paths in your URLs:

```
<link href="/css/grayscale.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Greatest answer of all time

Answer (score 0):

it will work 100%

step 1

```
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/assets/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
```

setp 2

```
<spring:url var="css" value="/resources/css/"/>
<spring:url var="js" value="/resources/js/"/>

<spring:url var="image" value="/resources/image/"/>
```

add a slash after value

step 3

add your style sheet like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="${css}/common/bootstrap.min.css">
```